I want to add the Visa click to pay button to my site but when the SDK is initializing I receive error "api key invalid"
To add the "Visa Click to Pay" button to my site, Visa documentation says that I should use their JS SDK link
This script is required on my HTML page
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js"></script>

when I initialized the SDK, I wrote this code
V.init({
    apikey: 'the "API Key" taken from Credentials section of visa developer center',
    encryptionKey: 'decoded "Shared Secret" using base64 and then decrypted using private key',
    settings: {
        locale: 'en_US',
        countryCode: 'US',
        displayName: 'Your Merchant Name'
    }
});

V.on('payment.success', function (response) {
    console.log('Payment successful:', response);
    // Handle successful payment here
});

V.on('payment.error', function (error) {
    console.error('Payment error:', error);
    // Handle payment error here
});

V.on('payment.cancel', function () {
    console.log('Payment cancelled');
    // Handle payment cancellation here
});

after the HTML page is loaded, the SDK made this list of requests:

GET https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/gtm 200 OK
GET https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/config 200 OK
GET https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/config.js 200 OK
GET https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/gtm.js 200 OK
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js 200 OK
POST https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/logging/logEvent 200 OK
POST https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/logging/logEvent 200 OK
GET https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/wallet-services-web/merchant 401 Unauthorized

response body
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "status": 401,
        "code": "9005",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "message": "Invalid ApiKey",
        "info": "http://api.visa.com/docs/errors/9005"
    }
}

Can you help me to determinate what is wrong from my side? Maybe I choose the wrong way to integrate the "Visa Click to pay" button into the site. Maybe I missed something in the code.
I tried to use value for encryptedKey the different values taken from the "credentials" section of the visa development portal, but the result is the same.
Related documentation
https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/visa-secure-remote-commerce/docs
Steps to receive decrypted shared secret the in encryptedKey
# cat encrypted_shared_secret.txt | base64 --decode > decoded_data.bin
# openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in decoded_data.bin -inkey private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 > decrypted_shared_secret.txt

Related screenshots


Is that a live API-key or a test API-key? If it's a live API key, the issue could be that you are using the wrong SDK - Hence the sandbox in https://sandbox.secure....

@DarkBee it is a sandbox mode and APi key taken from the test environment
